# How to set total number of ListView Items manually

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I want to implement paging functionality in my asp.net page. So I make ListView and DatePager for that.

```
<div class="pagination">
                    <div class="numeric">
                    <asp:DataPager ID="resultListPager" runat="server"
                       PagedControlID="resultList">
                       <Fields>
                          <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Link" ShowNextPageButton="False" PreviousPageText="< Prev" />
                          <asp:NumericPagerField ButtonType="Link" NumericButtonCssClass="numericLink" />
                          <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Link" ShowPreviousPageButton="false" ShowNextPageButton="False" ShowLastPageButton="True" />
                          <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Link" ShowPreviousPageButton="false" NextPageText="Next >" />
                       </Fields>
                    </asp:DataPager>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <asp:ListView ID="resultList" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceholder" OnPagePropertiesChanging="ChangePage">

                <LayoutTemplate>
                <ul class="items_list5">
                    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
                </ul>
                </LayoutTemplate>

                <ItemTemplate>
                <li class="cat_item">
                <div class="item_image">
                                <a href="#"><img src="<%#Eval("Image")%>" alt="" /></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item_description">
                                <%#Eval("Name")%>
                            </div>
                </li>
                </ItemTemplate>

                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                <div>Sorry - no items found.</div>
                </EmptyDataTemplate>
                </asp:ListView>
```

The problem is that as I'm getting only first 10 elements from database, paging shows only one page.

```
int totalCount;
List<GiftVoucher> vouchers = GiftVoucher.Search(querystring, pageNumber, count, out totalCount);
resultList.DataSource = vouchers;
resultList.DataBind();
```

For example if my totalCount is 50, I want to make my paging with 5 pages... Now it shows only one page, because I am getting only first 10 records from database?

So, how to set listview's total items counts to my totalCount variable manually?

Answer (score 0):

Switch to the ObjectDataSource and set both SelectMethod and SelectCountMethod. This way the list will get not only the current page but also the total number of items.